# Not compile-time constant expression in VS2017

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, visual-studio-2017, constexpr

VS2017 15.1 fails to compile the following code:

```
template<int data_size>
struct Data { };

template<int s>
struct Base
{
    static constexpr int size() { return s; }
};

template<int s>
struct Derived : Base<s>   // struct Derived
{
    Data<Base<s>::size()> data;
};

int main()
{
    Derived<1> c;
}
```

The error is:

> ```
> error C2975: 'data_size': invalid template argument for 'Data', expected compile-time constant expression
> note: see declaration of 'data_size'
> note: see reference to class template instantiation 'Derived<s>' being compiled
> ```

If I do not derive `Derived` from `Base`, the error disappears. With gcc 5.4.0 and clang 4.0.0 everything is fine in both cases.

Is anything wrong with this code?

Comment: Do you get the same error with `Data<size()> data` and `Data<Derived::size()> data`?

Comment: If you first call and store the result like so: `static constexpr auto size{ Base<s>::size() };`, you can use it right after: `Data<size> data;`. This compiles, but I'm not sure why directly putting it as a template argument doesn't.

Comment: @melpomene `Data<size()>` produces an error, `Data<Derived::size()>` works fine (but why?).

Comment: @melpomene `Data<size()> data` is illegal, since members of a dependent base class are not found during unqualified lookup.  But I wouldn't be surprised if MSVC allows it anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a Visual Studio bug. According to Visual Studio Feedback System [report](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/110435/not-compile-time-constant-expression.html), it has been fixed in Visual Studio 2019 version 16.2.

Comment: Looks like the issue is here again: https://godbolt.org/z/zvx555Ysf

Answer (score 1):

Since size is static there is no real reason to inherit from Base. The following code is working

```
template<int data_size>
struct Data 
{

};

template<int s>
struct Base
{
    static constexpr int size()  { return s; }
};

template<int s>
struct Derived 
{
    Data<Base<s>::size()> data;
};
int main()
{
    Derived<1> c;
}
```

If you still need to inherit from base you can do the following

```
template<int data_size>
struct Data 
{

};

template<int s>
struct Base
{
    static constexpr int size()  { return s; }
};

template<int s,int s1>
struct _Derived : Base<s>   // struct Derived
{
    Data<Base<s1>::size()> data;
};


template <int s>
using Derived = _Derived<s,s>;

int main()
{
    Derived<1> c;
}
```

I am not sure 100% why VS doesn't allow the same template arg to be used in the inheritance and the static function access. The above does the trick when I need it :)